# How would I get a .pdf file to open after one dismisses an alert (HTML). (Note: the alert pops up after an ID and password have been entered)

Tags: html, pdf, popup

I have done thorough research and couldn't find anything that doesn't involve clicking a button in the page and doesn't require a download of Adobe Acrobat.

Answer (score 0):

After the alert() redirect the user to pdf url:

```
alert('This is the alert. Click OK to continue');
window.location.href = "http://the.url.to/file.pdf";
```

Alternatively if you want to open the pdf in new window/tab then:

```
alert('This is the alert. Click OK to continue');
window.open("http://the.url.to/file.pdf");
```